# Django REST framework serializer return format as list instead of JSON

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

Hello i am trying to develop a simple REST API endpoint using Django rest framework.I tried checking similar questions but did not work.I want my output as (JSON Format):

```
{
    {
        "id": 1,
        "status": "ONLINE"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "status": "OFFLINE"
    }
}
```

but my output is (List Format):

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "status": "ONLINE"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "status": "OFFLINE"
    }
]
```

My models.py:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="OFFLINE")
```

my serializer.py:

```
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = '__all__'
```

and my views.py:

```
def device_list(request):
    devices = Device.objects.all()
    serializer = DeviceSerializer(devices, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: No idea what you're asking, expected and actual are identical

Comment: What i want is JSON format what i get is List format

Comment: You're misinterpreting your output. the first one isn't valid JSON and couldn't be read by a browser or produced by DRF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output you want is not valid json. {} is for dicts, maps, etc... and [] is for lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
def device_list(request):
    devices = Device.objects.all()
    serializer = DeviceSerializer(devices, many=True)
    return Response({"data":serializer.data})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return Response(serializer.data[0])
```